# How to use top middle and center inside a div

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a container within another container which I want to use three sections.  A  element at the top, an  element in the middle and a  element at the bottom.

Can someone help me figure out how to style those elements to display properly?

http://jsfiddle.net/WSFnX/877/

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class='main'>
    <div class='outer'>
        <div class='inner'>
            <b>header</b>
            <hr/>
            <h3>Middle Text</h3>
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/f0f/fff"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.main {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 900px;
    height: 600px;
    padding: 50px;
}

.outer {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background: #fafafa;
}

.inner {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.inner b {
    font-size: 0.65em;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner hr {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Top, Middle, and Bottom is vague. What do you want the final product to look like? Can you put a photoshop/paint example up? Are the elements supposed to be equally sized?

Comment: Do you want them to be equally spaced throughout the `inner` div? and all the same size or do you want the header text to be so small

Comment: do you want exact thing on this link http://jsfiddle.net/WSFnX/877/ ??

Comment: The white div in the middle.  I want <b>header</b> at the top, <h3>Middle Text</h3> in the middle and <img> at the very bottom.  centered well.  I tried several different things and none are working.

Comment: `.main .outer .inner{
    text-align:center;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/6tE7k/

You can change these:

```
min-height:500px;
min-height:100px;
```

to whatever height you need.

If you look at it on a fullscreen, you can see it's a div container within a div container. The nested div is set for 1024px.

Comment: I think I can work with this, my only problem is trying to get the <h3> text to center vertically in the middle div.

Comment: Kind of, except it has to be able to support longer text, notice: http://jsfiddle.net/6tE7k/2/

Comment: ya I was thinking i would have to use display: table-cell but couldn't get it to work right, this seems to work perfectly, thanks!

Comment: It's because the parent div needs to be set as display:table;

Glad we could get it working!